# Web API Multiple actions were found with GetAll() and GetByIds(int[] ids)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, parameters, asp.net-web-api-routing

Using the standard route:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

With these actions:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public string GetAll()
    {
        return "all";
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string GetById(int id)
    {
        return "single";
    }

    // GET api/values?ids=1&ids=2
    public string GetByIds([FromUri] int[] ids)
    {
        return "multiple";
    }
```

And make a request to **/api/values**, I get this exception:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
System.String GetAll() on type MvcApplication4.Controllers.ValuesController
System.String GetByIds(Int32[]) on type MvcApplication4.Controllers.ValuesController
```

I've been spinning my wheels trying to find a solution around this. It's my belief that the **GetAll** and **GetByIds** actions are considered **Multiple** here, but they aren't because the GetByIds has a different signature.

Is there a work around for this that doesn't involve adding `{action}` to the route?

Comment: Could you post the WebApi Route.Config?

Comment: Added @Fals, it's the standard bits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I found to do this is to combine the GetAll and GetByIds action and switch case the length of ids.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values/5
    public string GetById(int id)
    {
        return "single";
    }

    // GET api/values
    // GET api/values?ids=1&ids=2
    public string GetByIds([FromUri] int[] ids)
    {
        switch (ids.Length)
        {
            case 0:
                return "all";

            default:
                return "multiple";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is also the only solution I found for Web API 2.  However, in my case I must check for `ids == null` rather than `ids.Length == 0`.  I'm not sure if this was a change made in Web API 2, but if I call `api/values` without any values for `ids`, the array is `null` rather than empty.

Answer (score 2):

There currently is no out of box support for binding collection of values coming from Uri. Following is the issue regarding that and also the action disambiguation problem:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/322

Unfortunately, I cannot think of a work around related to the Action selection problem(without the '{action}') itself even though you solve the problem of model-binding to collection using a custom parameter binding like below:

```
public string GetByIds(int[] ids)
    {
        return "multiple";
    }
------------------------

config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, typeof(int[]), (paramDesc) => new SampleParameterBinding(paramDesc));

-------------------------

public class SampleParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    public SampleParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor desc)
        : base(desc)
    {
    }

    public override bool WillReadBody
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage currentRequest = actionContext.Request;

        NameValueCollection nvc = currentRequest.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();

        //TODO: ERROR CHECKS
        int[] ids = nvc["ids"].Split(',').Select(str => Int32.Parse(str)).ToArray();

        // Set the binding result here
        SetValue(actionContext, ids);

        // now, we can return a completed task with no result
        TaskCompletionSource<AsyncVoid> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<AsyncVoid>();
        tcs.SetResult(default(AsyncVoid));
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private struct AsyncVoid
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend attribute routing:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    // GET api/values?ids=1&ids=2
    [Route("values")]
    public string GetCollection([FromUri] IList<int> ids)
    {
        if (ids == null)
        {
          return "all";
        }
        return "multiple";
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [Route("values/{id:int}")]
    public string GetById(int id)
    {
        return "single";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: This is a hack. Why are you using WebAPI if you are not interesting in building a resource API? Putting the action in the URL destroys the orthogonality of verb and URL that HTTP/REST is intended to have; you might as well just use MVC, which is build for this sort of RPC.

Comment: In addition, you really ought not to post blocks of code without some sort of explanatory text.